# Urwid colored Text simplified

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my broken code (technically works but doesn't change color)

```
import urwid
txt = urwid.AttrMap(urwid.Text(u"Hello World"), 'dark blue')
fill = urwid.Filler(txt, 'top')
loop = urwid.MainLoop(fill)
loop.run()
```

Honestly all I want to do is change the color of the text, it seems so simple of a task but with urwid, a little confusing.

Here's how they did it in their example: https://github.com/urwid/urwid/blob/5c7bff3d381e855b483b7b65688ce2d4f53cdd1b/docs/manual/safe_combinations.py

Answer (score 3):

From the [manual](http://urwid.org/reference/widget.html#text), there is no argument for color:

> class urwid.Text(markup, align='left', wrap='space', layout=None)

You have to define a pallet, example:

```
import urwid

palette = [("text", "dark blue", 'white')]

text = urwid.Text(("text", u'Hello World'))
fill = urwid.Filler(text, 'top')
urwid.MainLoop(fill, palette).run()
```

[image]

For Display attributes, visit: http://urwid.org/tutorial/index.html#display-attributes

You can follow some advanced examples at: http://urwid.org/examples/index.html